# Splitting NMAP XML Files

Tags: xml, nmap

I have some extremely large NMAP XML save files that I'm trying to do some post processing on.  Unfortunately, because of the size of the files, I'm not being successful (at least, won't be before some time close to the heat death of the universe).

Is it possible to split one NMAP XML file into a number of smaller ones?  For example, split a scan of a class B into it's constituent class Cs?  Even just split in half would be a help.

FWIW...I'm modestly conversant in C, awk/sed and Python.  Just not so much XML.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [BaseX](http://basex.org/), which is an XML database engine. It also allows you to query your data using XPath/XQuery, so that you can extract the bits of information that you need without needing to split the original file.